# Calculate $\frac{1}{{1 - 100 + 500}} + \frac{{{2^2}}}{{{2^2} - 200 + 500}} + \ldots + \frac{{{{99}^2}}}{{{{99}^2} - 9900 + 500}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need a hint to solve this problem : Find the sum of

> $$ \frac{1}{{1 - 100 + 500}} + \frac{{{2^2}}}{{{2^2} - 200 + 500}} + \frac{{{3^2}}}{{{3^2} - 300 + 500}} +  +  \ldots  + \frac{{{{99}^2}}}{{{{99}^2} - 9900 + 500}}
> $$

Comment: Could you show what you have done?

Comment: @prayer smith It's $62.97...$

Comment: @michael-rozenberg  is this right  : $\frac{{{N^2}}}{{{N^2} - 100N + 500}} = 1 + \frac{1}{{100N + 500}} = 1 + \frac{1}{{100(N + 5)}}!
$

Comment: @prayer smith I think it's not true.

Comment: No way to simplify this. Just use a calculator...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\frac{N^2}{N^2-100N+500} = \frac{N^2}{N^2-100N+2500-2500+500} = \frac{N^2}{(N-50)^2-(10\sqrt{20})^2)} $

$ a = (50-10\sqrt{20})$

$S = \frac{AN+B}{N-a} + \frac{C}{N+a}$

Simplifying this

$S = \sum_{N=1}^{99} 1+ a^2\frac{1}{N^2-a^2} =  \sum_{N=1}^{99}1+ a^2\frac{1}{(\frac{N}{a})^2-1}$

$S= 99+(50-10\sqrt{20})^2*(-6.67) $

I evaluated the last sum by Wolfram Alpha, if anyone has an idea of how to evaluate that will be great